# Fix row height of every row in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, row-height

I'm working on Windows c#.

Firstly, the things those can not be change as my need are following:

1. The Size of `TableLayoutPanel` is fixed.
2. The Total # of columns are fixed.

Now, I want to set a fix height for all rows but as increasing the rows, if I set the `RowStyle` property to `Percent` with `100.0F` then it works fine for 3 to 4 items, but after 4-5 items, the control on one row overwrites controls on another row.

I have searched for this so more but i'm not able to get the proper answer. I have also tried the `AutoSize`, `Percent`, `Absolute` properties of `RowStyle`, even though it is not working.

So what to do and how? How can I achieve this?

Ultimately, I want to do same like as `DataGridView` of Windows C#.

Thanks in advance....

I'm working on WinForms...the sample code is here..

```
int cnt = tableLayout.RowCount = myDataTable.Rows.Count;

tableLayout.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 200);

for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
{

    Label lblSrNo = new Label();
    lblSrNo.Text = i.ToString(); 

    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Text = ""; 
    txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(69, 20);

    tableLayout.Controls.Add(lblSrNo, 0, i - 1);
    tableLayout.Controls.Add(txt, 1, i - 1);
}

tableLayout.RowStyles.Clear();

foreach (RowStyle rs in tableLayout.RowStyles)                
    tableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
```

The label and textboxes are working fine for 4-5 #of rows but whenever the #of row(in this case, variable cnt in for loop) increases, the rows are overwriting each other that is one control overwrite to another...I had drag-drop the TableLayoutPanel control and created just one row and 2 columns manually.

So please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Is this WPF?  WinForms?  I think you could do a lot to improve this question.  How about some code?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Hi..i have attached the sample code, so please check it and tell me what is wrong with it??     Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know Winforms.  I've added the "winforms" tag to your question so other Winforms developers will see it.

Answer (score 15):

I'm still new to tableLayoutPanels myself, but I noticed that at the bottom of your code, you're Clearing all the rowstyles from the collection, then you're trying to iterate through them in your foreach loop.

You did this:

```
tableLayout.RowStyles.Clear();   //now you have zero rowstyles

foreach (RowStyle rs in tableLayout.RowStyles)   //this will never execute
    tableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
```

Try this instead.

```
TableLayoutRowStyleCollection styles =
    tableLayout.RowStyles;
foreach (RowStyle style in styles){
    // Set the row height to 20 pixels.
    style.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
    style.Height = 20;
}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Edit:  I just realized that adding N rows doesn't add N rowstyles that you can iterate through.  I think what's happening is that you're adding N rows, but none of them have a rowstyles.

I suppose you can Clear() the rowstyles, then just add N rowstyles similar to how you're already doing.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to increase the row height of table layout panel.

1. Look into the following link :
   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d80db8e1-d6cc-48b8-957f-0f73263c6d4a/how-to-change-the-row-height-of-a-tablelayoutpanel-at-runtime?forum=winforms

   It specifies by setting the YourTableLayoutPanel.RowStyles[index].Height int he code behind class.
2. The other way is to set the row height in the designer of your UI. Through UI, go into Rows properties of the panel, select the row and set the required height using percent or absolute